# how to share photo from facebook app

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want so share photos to my Facebook timeline from my application. I created a quiz application which gives a certificate.  I want to show an image of that certificate as a photo on Facebook. I checked the Facebook php SDK, but couldnt figure out how to do that. Is there any specific code to do this? I saw some Facebook apps that are sharing images directly to my wall.

Heres some code i tried and failed:

```
require 'lib/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxx',
));
$photo = "";
$message = "Checkout my photo";
$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', array(
                                         'source' => '@' . $photo,
                                         'message' => $message,
                                         )
                                      );
echo '<pre>Photo ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted a complete code on how to create an album as well as upload photo on another question, you can refer at: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/12810351/828705